# I'm having a trouble with encoding in Python

Tags: python, unicode, encoding

I have been using PHP for a while,

but now I am trying to learn Python.
I never really had a serious problem with encoding on PHP. At least I could solve in few minutes. but I have spent hours to solve encoding problems in python, and I still can't solve it.

So my problem is that I want to print a Japanese string to a file using Shell redirect using this command

```
python make_csv.py > csvfile.csv
```

But the Japanese texts that are printed on the csv file are all messed up.

I've tried several solutions like using .encode('utf-8') etc, but still no luck
and I also encounter this error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 5: ordinal not in range(128)
```

how can I solve this?
please help.

Comment: Show your code.  Just the error message won't tell us what your mistake is (though my guess is that you opened the file in text mode instead of binary mode).

Comment: The most common problem is that .encode('utf8') method is usefull on `unicode` type not `str`. Use .decode(<type of decoding in your file>) first and then .encode('utf8') or simply use unicode string `u'ユニコード'` .

Comment: how can I open a gz file in binary mode?

Comment: this might be related problem, when I type python on my terminal and go to python mode, I cant even type Japanese character, the Japanese text that I just type is automatically converted to weird characters

Comment: You didn't have encoding problems in PHP because it doesn't give a shit about its data. A string can contain anything even if it's a mix of different encodings that will not render properly anywhere.

Comment: i think my problem is default encoding in python. how can I change that?

Comment: I've fixed the problem. it was unquote_plus !!

Comment: I changed the subject of your question to make it less... flaming. It isn't surprising that you find some subject in a language new to you less intuitive than in a language you're already used to. Take it easy, and you'll learn

Comment: Thanks @Eli Bendersky I've solved the problem, so it's ok now. endocing

Comment: By reproducing the problem in a 10-line example and posting the code, as Sven said.   The error message is self-explanatory - codepoint 0xe2 (http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e2/index.htm) is not ASCII, and it's more likely to be in French text than Japanese.  My guess is that it's not part of any string at all, but part of the gzip binary.  But there's no way to tell if you don't post some code.

Comment: Calling `.encode("utf8")` is never the answer.  You should not have opened the stream in binary mode.

Comment: You should really post your code - because it seems you're doing this wrongTM. `with open("test.csv", "r", encoding="UTF-8") as file: print(file.read())` should reproduce the text just fine (assuming the shell can print unicode and it is encoded using UTF-8 obviously).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting your environment variable `PYTHONIOENCODING` to utf8. That will make Python use that encoding instead of none by default.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**: I removed my comment because it was not really helpful for the question because I misread it...

Now here my to cents that could perhaps help: You print the japanese text to the standard output (sys.stdout). Notice, that in Windows the default encoding of sys.stdout is CP850 and not UTF-8 ...

(To change Python's default io encoding have a look to the solution pointed out by tchrist: set PYTHONIOENCODING to UTF-8)

Comment: No, you don't want to open it in binary mode. You want to specify the `encoding=utf8` in the open.

Comment: Downvote removed after edit. You're right, it's a bug in the API.  Python3 fixes it so that you can supply an encoding argument to `open` so you no longer need to deal with `codecs` fu, but it leaves a bunch of other things just hanging. For example, `subprocess.Popen` is also missing an encoding argument. Am I the only one who finds this confusing?